# How to conditionally run npm script

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I am looking for a cross-platform way of conditionally running a step in my build script.

I have a build step that is expensive, however checking to see if it is necessary is relatively quick.  I have created a script that returns a non-zero error code if it is not necessary to do the build step.  How can I write my npm script to only run the build if the check passes but provide errors if the build step fails?

Example package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "schema:build": "npm run schema:rebuild-check && npm run schema:force-build",
    "schema:rebuild-check": "node tools/schema is-rebuild-necessary",
    "schema:force-build": "npm run schema:validate && npm run schema:generate-index && npm run schema:bundle"
}
```

The problem with the above is that if the rebuild is not necessary my entire build fails.  I can't just swallow the exit code with something like exitzero because I want to know if any of the commands fail in the schema:force-build script.

Comment: This is failing on windows.  From what I have read online this should work:
"schema:build": "npm run schema:rebuild-check && npm run schema:force-build || echo \"Skipping schema build\""
Because the || or operator should run the second command if the first fails.  However on my windows machine it errors out at the first statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises from two things:

1) If an npm script exits with a non-zero code npm will always complain

2) Need to provide an "else" that returns non zero using the || operator

Working solution:

```
"schema:build": "node tools/schema is-rebuild-necessary && npm run schema:force-build || echo Skipping schema build",
"schema:force-build": "npm run schema:validate && npm run schema:generate-index && npm run schema:bundle"
```